# Why does our vote limit change?

Tags: support, votes

Just the other day I could cast 38 votes, then yesterday I could only do 32. Is there a factor affecting our vote limits? Perhaps like saving-up?

Answer (score 2):

What reported by @MrHen is correct. The limit is 40 votes but, for what I have noticed, you need to vote 10 questions before you vote for 30 answers.
For example, if you vote 2 questions, and then vote 30 answers, then you already reached your limit.

The order of the votes is not important; you could vote 4 questions, 15 answers, 2 questions, and 15 answers, and you would have reached your daily limit.

The [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) reports the following sentence, about voting:

> A maximum of 40 votes can be cast per user per day, however, to reach the maximum you must vote on at least 10 questions.

Comment: Almost there. Check out [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256) by one of the devs for how this is actually implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This was changed per [a blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/):

> The daily vote limit used to be 30 votes per day; we’ve increased that to a maximum of 40 votes per day — but only if you vote on a combination of answers and questions. This isn’t as significant as you might think, since it is exceedingly rare for users to even hit the 30 vote daily cap.